# Something wrong with Chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

Recently just got one chat room invite
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/96672

when i go inside nothing in. I don't know what's wrong. It's just show me room info and one message and also i can't send message in chat room.

what's wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Well, uh, not sure if it's the case, but the image your showing is a transcript of the chat, not the "actual" chat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking at a transcript.

Click the <kbd>join this room</kbd> button under the calendar icon.
This will redirect you to the actual room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96672/room-for-lakhan-and-m-d